# Index out of bounds in Python

Tags: python, index-error

Could someone help me with what I need to change to resolve the index out-of-bounds problem in this code? There are codes before the beginning and later too. Do you think it would be relevant?

```py
print("1. Sum of Squared Differences") 

print("2. Correlation Coefficient") 

print("3. Normalized Cross-Correlation") 

cross_image_type = input("Enter the type of cross image referencing: ") 

if (cross_image_type == "1"): 

    h = len(grey_picture_data[0]) 

    w = len(grey_picture_data[0]) 

    r = np.zeros((h,w)) 

    for k in range(0,h): 

        for l in range(0,w): 

            for i in range(0,w): 

                for j in range(0,h):      

                        r[i][j] += (((grey_picture_data[i+k][j+l]) - (grey_picture_data_2[k][l]))**2)
```

The output on screen -

```
Enter the name of a color image: crosswalk.jpg
Enter the name of the color template file: crosswalk_template.jpg
1. Sum of Squared Differences
2. Correlation Coefficient
3. Normalized Cross-Correlation
Enter the type of cross image referencing: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "d:\purdue\engr 133\proj.py", line 206, in <module>
    r[i][j] += (((grey_picture_data[i+k][j+l]) - (grey_picture_data_2[k][l]))**2)

IndexError: index 683 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 683
```

Comment: The first dimension is `h`.  The second dimension is `w`.  That means `k` and `j` are first dimension, and `l` and `i` are second dimension.  That means `r[i][j]` has the coordinates backwards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `grey_picture_data[i+k][j+l]`, what values do you think will be possible for `i+k`? Why? (Hint: what is the largest possible value for `i`, according to the `for` loop? What is the largest possible value for `k`? What will you get if you add those numbers together?) Are all of those valid indices for `grey_picture_data`? Separately: where the code says `h = len(grey_picture_data[0])` and then `w = len(grey_picture_data[0])`, what do you think this means? **What will happen** if `grey_picture_data` is not square?

Comment: (And what if `grey_picture_data2` has a different size?)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
h = len(grey_picture_data[0]) 

w = len(grey_picture_data[0]) 

r = np.zeros((h,w)) 

for k in range(0,h): 

    for l in range(0,w): 
        
        for i in range(0,w):
                
                for j in range(0,h):
                    
                    r[k][l] = r[k][l] + grey_picture_data[i][j]*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*(i*k/w+j*l/h))
```

Comment: IndexError: index 683 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 683 at the same line.    Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  r[k][l] = r[k][l] + grey_picture_data[i][j]*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*(i*k/w+j*l/h))
Traceback (most recent call last):